# How Do I retrieve a string value JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a returned string result from an API and it looks like this.. for the life of me, I cannot retried the WorkID value!

The returned string is a json string:

```
{"notes":"","RecordsStatus":"{\"0\":{\"WorkID\":\"0090210\",\"Message\":\"Record Created\"}}"}
```

It has two parts:
“notes” and “RecordStatus”.
If message is empty, means the batch is imported without error.
In RecordStatus, there are two parts too.
First is the index number of the record, and it has second part that the key for the record created(in my case it’s the WorkID) and a message tells the record is created or updated(in my case, it’s created).

```
Array
(
    [notes] => 
    [RecordsStatus] => {"0":{"WorkID":"0090210","Message":"Record Created"}}
)
```

Do a Var_dump() of decoded_json results in this:

```
array(2) {
  ["notes"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["RecordsStatus"]=>
  string(52) "{"0":{"WorkID":"0090210","Message":"Record Created"}}"
}
```

I tried

```
foreach($decoded_json as $item) { 
    $uses = $item['RecordsStatus'][0]['WorkID']; //etc
}
```

but does not work

Comment: RecordsStatus status is also stringified, either fix at source or decode it again, ie.: `$uses = json_decode($item['RecordsStatus'], true)[0]['WorkID'];`

Comment: And note that the var_dump told you this already: `["RecordsStatus"]=>string(52) "{"0":{"WorkID":"0090210","Message":"Record Created"}}"` tells us that the content is just 52 characters of plain text, not navigable data.

Comment: Thank you… I will try strpos() and get the value that way if that makes sense